# Issue in uploading gem to Geminabox

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

I stood up a Rack server with Geminabox, running on my machine at http://localhost:9292. Now I was trying to upload the gem to the server (from a different tab on the terminal acting like a client), but when I type:

```
gem sources -a http://localhost:9292
```

I get the following error:

```
Error fetching http://localhost:9292:
bad response Not Found 404 (http://localhost:9292/specs.4.8.gz)
```

There is a trailing colon and I'm a bit lost, any help on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to upload at least one gem before Geminabox starts to serve the necessary files.

(I know this is an old question but I came here from google so others might as well)

Comment: My next question would be exactly how the heck you upload at least one gem.

Comment: No-one wrote code to handle this, I assume. For doing cache-only gem server, I think there is better solutions than geminabox anyway.

Comment: @Smar what are the better solutions?

Comment: @sixty4bit: one example is just to use something that can cache, i.e. transparent cache proxy or proxy everything through a web server that can cache (like nginx). What is best for you depends on your situation.